# using keyword takes less space?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it true that if i use the following, it will take less resources and the cleanup will be faster?

```
 using (TextReader readLogs = File.OpenText("C:\\FlashAuto\\Temp\\log.txt"))
 {
      //my stuff
 }
```

as compared to:

```
 TextReader readLogs = new StreamReader("C:\\FlashAuto\\Temp\\log.txt");
 //my stuff
readLogs.Close();
readLogs.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The difference between those examples isn't performance, but exception safety. `using` creates a `try...finally` block in the background.

> A using statement of the form:
>
> ```
> using (ResourceType resource = expression) embedded-statement
> ```
>
> corresponds to the expansion:
>
> ```
> { 
>    ResourceType resource = expression; 
>    try {     
>      embedded-statement 
>    } 
>    finally { 
>      // Dispose of resource 
>    } 
> }
> ```

For reference type the disposing happens via:

> ```
> finally {  
>   if (resource != null) ((System.IDisposable)resource).Dispose(); 
> }
> ```

*From ECMA-344 C# Language Specification 4th Edition*

---

You also don't need to call both `Close` and `Dispose`. Those functions are equivalent.

Comment: Actually im doing some logging stuff after every 10 seconds in the UI thread. Every time it reads the log and displays in a multiline textbox, a huge chunk of memory is taken. But if i update the textbox without reading file by using some status message of my own, there is no change in the memory.

Comment: @musefan the quote formatting was deliberate, since these are quotes from the spec.

Comment: Fair enough, should probably add references at point of posting next time though, avoid confusion for innocent readers ;)

Answer (score 7):

The first sample is short-hand for:

```
TextReader readLogs = File.OpenText("C:\\FlashAuto\\Temp\\log.txt");
try
{
    // My stuff
}
finally
{
    if (readLogs != null)
    {
        ((IDisposable)readLogs).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Its not that its quicker, its that `readLogs` will be cleaned up even if an exception occurrs which won't happen in your second example.

See [using Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) for more information.

There is no need to call both `Close` and `Dispose`, internally the `Close` method does the same work as the `Dispose` method (its just renamed because developers are used to having a method called `Close`).

---

**Update:** There is also no difference between calling `File.OpenText` and `new StreamReader` - internally `File.OpenText` just creates and returns a new instance of `StreamReader`.

Comment: Actually im doing some logging stuff after every 10 seconds in the UI thread. Every time it reads the log and displays in a multiline textbox, a huge chunk of memory is taken. But if i update the textbox without reading file by using some status message of my own, there is no change in the memory.

Comment: @Rohan It sounds like the difference is in the `// My stuff` bit - if you are reading the entire file every time then this probably will use up a chunk of memory.

Comment: `File.OpenText` should be outside the `try...finally` block. Your code wouldn't compile because `readLogs` isn't guaranteed to be initialized in your finally clause.

Comment: @Justin: you were right. Changing //my stuff did the job. Thanks for all the help